# Search by hitting enter?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering if anyone can help me please?

I've currently got a search form setup, i'd like to remove the 'search' button and allow the user to search by typing and then click enter into the 'search-field'.

```php
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <input type="search"
            class="search-field"
            placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Our Site', 'placeholder' ) ?>"
            value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>"
            name="s"
            title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>"
        />
    </label>
    <input type="submit"
        class="search-submit"
        value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>"
    />
</form>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: *"search by typing and then click enter into the 'search-field'* ... isn't this standard behaviour - with or without a *submit* button (unless you're on a phone/tablet)?

Comment: You are escaping the HTML attribute, which is very good, however you are not escaping the *one* attribute that contains user input: the text input's value attribute. That makes you vulnerable to [reflected XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)#Stored_and_Reflected_XSS_Attacks).